# How to find a minimal path without using a differential equation?

Tags: geometry, maxima-minima

When browsing my son's math book, I stumbled upon a problem which I do not know how to approach **at his level**. This is a book for 11 years old, which is the 6th year of school ("6ème" in France).

The problem is the following

[image]

> `C` and `D` are villages which are at, respectively 9 and 3 km from a
>   railway (the `EXF` line).
>
> They will build a station (denoted by `X`) on the railway in such a
>   place where the distance to the villages `CX + XD` is the smallest.
>
> Where should `X` be placed?

I took the easy way by creating a function which depends on `EX` and found the root of its derivative - which gave me the `EX` minimizing the distance.

Now the harder part is to find the solution appropriate for an 11 years old. Out of the possibly useful things they **do not know** yet are Pythagorean and Thales' theorems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $D'$ be the reflection of $D$ across the railway line.
Then the distance from $X$ to $D'$ is the same as that from $X$ to $D$, 
and the shortest path from $C$ to $D'$ is a straight line.  Place the station where this line intersects the railway line.

[image]

Comment: This is clever, thanks. But then all the distances would just be decoys? (which I find hard to believe to be the case in a standard schoolbook)

Comment: Robert beat me to the answer, so I'll add this here: a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VfbUccGt8vA) about this problem.

Comment: @nickgard: at 3:00 in this video, the page looked like the first of my two or three ones when I was dissecting the derivative :) Nice video, thanks.

Comment: From the measurements given you can determine the distance $XF$ in proportion to $EF$ ($\frac{XF}{EF}=\frac{1}{4}$) without resorting to the Pythagoras theorem or interpreting a map where $x$ marks the spot.